# How to reference and cite the osgeo package from Python

Tags: citations, reference-request

i am a bit confused about osgeo, osgeo.gdal, osgeo.ogr and osgeo.osr. I want to cite and reference all my used Python libraries which i used for my masterthesis. I am not sure if it is enough to cite the osgeo package or if i have to mention gdal etc. as well. Also i can't find any information about the author or a reference for the osgeo Python library.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to cite and reference all my used Python libraries which i used for my masterthesis.

It is usually enough to cite just the package (not individual libraries), unless there are special circumstances.

Libraries / datasets with a science background (rule of thumb: papers were published introducing the library and/or it is part of an academic project) usually have somewhere on their websites some information about how it should be cited. In those cases, you should obviously use that. Example for MatPower - a Matlab package for power systems analysis (emphasis mine):

> Terms of Use
>   Please see the LICENSE file for the details. But here is the summary
>   ...
>
> Beginning with version 5.1, the code in MATPOWER is distributed under
>   the 3-clause BSD license. MATPOWER is distributed in the hope that it
>   will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY. While not required by the
>   terms of the license, **we do request that publications derived from the
>   use of MATPOWER explicitly acknowledge that fact by citing [2]**.
>   Additionally, we request that publications derived from the use of the
>   MATPOWER Optimal Scheduling Tool (MOST), explicitly acknowledge that
>   fact by citing [4] as well as [2].
>
> - **[2]    R. D. Zimmerman, C. E. Murillo-Sánchez, and R. J. Thomas, "MATPOWER: Steady-State Operations, Planning and Analysis Tools for Power Systems Research and Education," Power Systems, IEEE Transactions on, vol. 26, no. 1, pp. 12-19, Feb. 2011.**
> - [4]  C. E. Murillo-Sánchez, R. D. Zimmerman, C. L. Anderson, and R. J. Thomas, "Secure Planning and Operations of Systems with
>     Stochastic Sources, Energy Storage and Active Demand," Smart Grid,
>     IEEE Transactions on, vol. 4, no. 4, pp. 2220-2229, Dec. 2013.

For libraries with no such information, it is usually enough to put the link, or permalink if at all possible, to the website as a reference.

You should also check the institution's (or publishing venues's) reference guidelines, there should be something about citing online resources.

Comment: Uh, another [crayon license](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/how-can-a-crayon-license-be-a-problem).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I'm sorry, I don't understand. Do you mean the example I provided, the license of OsGeo or some other part of my answer?

Comment: I meant to say that Matpower has a crayon license.